# Trouble with Blank Ionic Project (newbie)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have given this an honest shot and spent hours trying to resolve this via tutorials, examples, and videos. I'm finally throwing in the towel on this one and am in need of some extra sets of eyes. I cannot for the life of me figure out why my welcome screen is not showing on my index! It show's up with "ionic blank start" at the top and in the console you see that "welcome.html" was loaded via xhr but it's never displayed. Here are my files:

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

## templates/welcome.html

```
<div ng-controller="WelcomeCtrl">
    The welcome page
</div>
<h1>welcome welcome</h1>
```

## js/app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('welcome', {
    url: '/welcome',
    abstract:true,
    templateUrl:'templates/welcome.html',
    controller:'WelcomeCtrl'
  })
  .state('sign-up', {
    url: '/sign-up',
    views: {
      tempalteUrl: 'templates/sign-up.html',
      controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/welcome');
})
```

## js/controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('WelcomeCtrl', function($scope) {})
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error in console?

Comment: Nope, no errors. The only thing that shows in the console is: `XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8100/templates/welcome.html".`

Comment: I think you need an <ion-nav-view> element inside (or instead of) the ion-content. You also don't need the ng-controller attribute in your template...the controller is setup with the state routing.

Comment: I have just added an answer. Please try that.

Comment: FYI, you should post an answer instead of editing an answer into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ion-nav-view` tag like this in your index.html -

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</ion-content>
```

This tag is necessary when you are working with states. Otherwise ionic shows a blank screen as it cannot find where to render the template.

I haven't tested this with your application, so you can give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed :(

Comment: Can you create a plnkr so we can try on that?

Comment: Anyways you should use what I said, as it is necessary. The problem might be more than that I am guessing.

Comment: The content is loaded now and I can see it via inspector but the `div.scroll` is at `height:0` which is why I can't see my content. Any idea why?

Comment: Ideally it should not happen. Make sure you are not setting height in any of css files. If not, then try setting min-height and height property of .scroll as 100% !important.

Comment: Yes I just added the code that ended up working for me. I got it without any CSS hacks too. The solution is not so much in your answer but that definitely put me closer so I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the advice of Sam + remove the `abstract:true,`  line in your state provider.

Abstract needs a child view in addition to be displayed, usually this is used for tab navigation in apps.

You have also declared the WelcomeCtrl in your html template

```
<div ng-controller="WelcomeCtrl">
```

This is not needed as you have it already declared in your state provider config.